# If condition works not so as I expect it

Tags: django, wagtail

On screenshot below you can see Im trying to save this model given one value for "RESULTAT 1 HZ" and empty value for "RESULTAT 1 HZ" on downside. In my `my_callback` Im doing some calculation but as you can see only if both of fields are not `None`. So, why I get error that shown on second screenshot?
`TypeError
Exception Value: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

[image]

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender='tournament.GroupstageTournamentModel')
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # Point for first half time
    if not (instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None and instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None):
        if instance.team_1_first_halftime_score > instance.team_2_first_halftime_score:
            instance.team_1_first_halftime_point = 2
```

[image]

Here is my Traceback  http://dpaste.com/0DDP4QC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not (
   instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None and 
   instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None
):
```

This condition will be `False` only if both of the following are `None` which will result in comparing of `int` and `None` type this results in Error as you have described above

You probably meant to have following

```
if not (
   instance.team_1_first_halftime_score is None or
   instance.team_2_first_halftime_score is None
):
```

Or additional condition

```
if instance.team_1_first_halftime_score and not instance.team_2_first_halftime_score:
```

which would mean you also need

```
if not instance.team_1_first_halftime_score and instance.team_2_first_halftime_score:
```